# IIS In-process session stays active after iisreset or machine reboot

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, iis-7, session-state

We have a web site where someone has hijacked a computer with the necessary client certificates, and is signing in attempting to change data to steal money. The web site uses IIS 7, in-process sessions, client certificates, .Net 2.0, and the ASP.Net membership system. We tried IISRESET and also rebooting the machine, but our sessions stay active even after this is done - I was still logged in after rebooting the machine, waiting for it to come back, then refreshing the page.

Any ideas on how to clear all sessions easily?

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <!--
    <location path="" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    -->
    <connectionStrings>
        <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
        ...
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        ...
        <add key="CSSFriendly-JavaScript-Path" value="~/JavaScript"/>
        <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="5000"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>
        <healthMonitoring>
            <!--  Event Log Provider being added. -->
            <providers>
                <remove name="EventLogProvider"/>
                <add name="EventLogProvider" type="System.Web.Management.EventLogWebEventProvider,System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            </providers>
            <!--  Event mapping provides a friendly name to the events based on the WebBaseErrorEvent class.  -->
            <eventMappings>
                <remove name="All Errors"/>
                <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent,System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647"/>
            </eventMappings>
            <!-- Rule tying the "All Errors" event mapping to the EventLog Provider.  -->
            <rules>
                <remove name="All Errors Default"/>
                <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" custom=""/>
            </rules>
        </healthMonitoring>
        <siteMap defaultProvider="CustomSiteMap" enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <add name="CustomSiteMap" type="CustomSiteMap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" siteMapFile="web.sitemap"/>
            </providers>
        </siteMap>
        <membership hashAlgorithmType="...">
            <providers>
                <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="ADRSAMembershipProvider.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
                <!-- Standard: add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/-->
                <add name="WWW" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="CustomerDB" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="www.asuedraw.com" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="[1-9][0-9]{3,11}"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
        <roleManager enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
                <add name="WWW" connectionStringName="CustomerDB" applicationName="www.asuedraw.com" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <authentication mode="Forms"/>
        <pages masterPageFile="~/Web.master" styleSheetTheme="Default" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
                <add tagPrefix="rsweb" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
                <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false"/>
            <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
            <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule"/>
            <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression"/>
        </httpModules>
        <customErrors defaultRedirect="/ErrorPage.aspx"/>
        <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
            <buildProviders>
                <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            </buildProviders>
        </compilation>
        <trace enabled="true" localOnly="false" mostRecent="true" requestLimit="200"/>
    </system.web>
    <!-- Used for the RSA membership provider -->
    <system.runtime.remoting>
        <application>
            <client>
                <wellknown type="SecurID4Net.IPipelineFactory, SecurID4Net.Interfaces" url="..."/>
                <!--wellknown type="SecurID4Net.IPipelineFactory, SecurID4Net.Interfaces"
                                     url="tcp://.../IPipelineFactory" /-->
            </client>
            <channels>
                <channel ref="tcp client"/>
            </channels>
        </application>
    </system.runtime.remoting>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" compilerOptions="/warnaserror-" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
            </compiler>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" compilerOptions="/optioninfer+" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.webServer>
        <!-- 
                The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
                Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
            -->
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="HHDataBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomerInfo" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomerInfo1"/>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICashTransfer" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="customBinding0">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding/>
                    <httpTransport/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="customBinding1">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding/>
                    <httpsTransport/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_ICashTransfer">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" maxSessionSize="2048">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    </binaryMessageEncoding>
                    <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false"/>
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="HHDataBehavior" name="HHData">
                <endpoint address="..." binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBinding1" contract="HHData"/>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="..." binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomerInfo" contract="CustomerServ.ICustomerInfo" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomerInfo"/>
            <endpoint address="..." binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICashTransfer" contract="CashTransferStatusService.ICashTransfer" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICashTransfer"/>
            <endpoint address="..." binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ICashTransfer" contract="CashTransfer.ICashTransfer" name="CustomBinding_ICashTransfer"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <!--
    </location>
-->
    <location path="Logon.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="test.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="clientaccesspolicy.xml">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure sessionState is set to be inproc?
Please paste your web.config (sesssion settings).

It is possible that your application uses sessionState settings from machine.config.

Comment: I noticed that `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />` wasn't in the web.config, so I added it; however, it did not boot me off the site after an iisreset.